# Python - code to convert any epoch time to formatted datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there some universal way to convert any epoch time in Python 3.6 or 3.7.  I got code working for one epoch time, but I'm calling various REST APIs, and some have more precision than others.

I got it working by dividing the specific time by 100000000.  But if possible, I would like one function to convert epoch time, no matter how many digits it is.
If that's not possible with a built-in function, then is the best way to test the number of digits, and just divide by the appropriate number.

Another post suggested using time.strftime but I couldn't get that to work.

I've seen several StackOver flow talk about the eror "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" which I get, but none addressed the concept of having one convert to handle all possible formats.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as datetime1  #still confused about this 
                              #sometimes I use other functions that require the 
                              #the first import above. 
import time

epoch_time1 = 1598653800
epoch_time2   = 1598653800006864384
# epoch_time2   = 1598653800006864384 / 100000000  #this works 
quoteTimeDTObj1 = datetime1.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time1)
#quoteTimeDTObj1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', epoch_time1)
print("quoteTimeDTObj1=" + str(quoteTimeDTObj1))

quoteTimeDTObj2 = datetime1.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time2)
#quoteTimeDTObj2 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', epoch_time2)
print("quoteTimeDTObj2=" + str(quoteTimeDTObj2))
```

Comment: Apparently you're getting epoch time in nanoseconds in some cases and in milliseconds (common) in other cases? You could just check the size of the value and assume anything over a certain value (likely 2,147,483,647) to be nanoseconds, but of course this may cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works, assuming you sometime receive epoch time in milliseconds and sometimes in nanoseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime


def epoch_to_dt(epoch_time):
    if epoch_time> 2147483647:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time / 100000000)
    else:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)


print(epoch_to_dt(1598653800))
print(epoch_to_dt(1598653800006864384))
```

Result:

```
2020-08-29 08:30:00
2020-08-29 08:30:00.006864
```

The `datetime` module doesn't want to do what's done here: assume a large value automatically means nanoseconds are intended. The standard epoch time is milliseconds as either an integer value, or as a floating point value with the fractional part indicating parts smaller than a millisecond, which I would recommend using in your own code as well.

As for the import confusion: it's a bit of a legacy thing. Importing `datetime` from `datetime` is indeed confusing. The first `datetime` in `from datetime import datetime` is the module, the second one is a class with useful class methods (these are the functions you often want).

It's probably best to always `from datetime import datetime`, and import other parts as well if you need them like `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`. Or have multiple import statements, if you prefer.

The reason I picked 2,147,483,647 seemingly at random is that this is the maximum integer value for a 32-bit integer and epoch time is not normally defined beyond it. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Of course, different solutions to the Year 2038 problem may cause the code above to become a problem, which is why I would recommend representing epoch time in your code to always mean 'milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00' (with our without fractions), to avoid future issues.

Comment: Are those the only two formats for epoch time?  I was using a len(str(epochtime)) as a temporary get around, but I was afraid there might be some with 1000s, some with 100,000 some with 100000000.

Comment: They are not really two formats - I would say only the millisecond one is normal. The nanosecond one (or a microsecond one, like you suggest) is an exception. It could be hard to tell a microsecond one from a nanosecond one, if you didn't know. I.e. is it micro seconds, or nanoseconds somewhere in the 70's? That why you would do better to represent these numbers as float, if they're not whole milliseconds. In your case, the question is: where are the values coming from? What do you know about the possible formats?